# Why shapeless `everywhere` combinator works inside a method but not in a `val`?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given this code:

```
import shapeless._
import poly._

object EverywhereValAndDef {

  sealed trait Tree[T]
  case class Leaf[T](t: T) extends Tree[T]
  case class Node[T](left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T]

  val tree: Tree[Int] =
    Node(
      Node(
        Node(
          Leaf(1),
          Node(
            Leaf(2),
            Leaf(3))),
        Leaf(4)),
      Node(
        Leaf(5),
        Leaf(6)))

  object inc extends ->((i: Int) => i + 1)

  def afterIncDef = everywhere(inc)(tree) // works

  val afterIncVal = everywhere(inc)(tree) // fails

  val expected: Tree[Int] =
    Node(
      Node(
        Node(
          Leaf(2),
          Node(
            Leaf(3),
            Leaf(4))),
        Leaf(5)),
      Node(
        Leaf(6),
        Leaf(7)))

  def eqDef = expected == afterIncDef

  def eqVal = expected == afterIncVal

}
```

in a repl session I get this results:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> EverywhereValAndDef.eqDef
res0: Boolean = true

scala> EverywhereValAndDef.eqVal
res1: Boolean = false

scala> EverywhereValAndDef.tree
res2: EverywhereValAndDef.Tree[Int] = Node(Node(Node(Leaf(1),Node(Leaf(2),Leaf(3))),Leaf(4)),Node(Leaf(5),Leaf(6)))

scala> EverywhereValAndDef.afterIncDef
res3: EverywhereValAndDef.Tree[Int] = Node(Node(Node(Leaf(2),Node(Leaf(3),Leaf(4))),Leaf(5)),Node(Leaf(6),Leaf(7)))

scala> EverywhereValAndDef.afterIncVal
res4: EverywhereValAndDef.Tree[Int] = Node(Node(Node(Leaf(1),Node(Leaf(2),Leaf(3))),Leaf(4)),Node(Leaf(5),Leaf(6)))
```

Why `everywhere` is not working in the `val` case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move the definitions of `Tree`, `Leaf` and `Node` out of `EverywhereValAndDef` to the top level (or to some other object) then the problem goes away.

I don't have a definitive answer, but it would appear to be a subtle initialization order issue colliding with this Scala macros [issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7755).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what's going on here?

Comment: In the val case the instance isn't found; in the def case it is. I'm guessing that there's some difference in the relative order of instance materialization vs. Symbol initialization of the sealed family between the def and the val cases.